# Mvvm - retrofit service class, I don't know, what this method mean

Tags: java, android, mvvm, retrofit

I have some piece of code, used in MVVM structure to create Retrofit service, there's one method, that I don't understand at all, can I have any explanation of it? What does those 
"< S >", and "S" mean? Here's the code

```
private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("some_http")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass){
    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

S is a class type parameter
It's used to specify the output type class to be the same as the input class is.

Try looking through this

[Service Generator Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666960/service-generator-retrofit)